# Initialize g_hash_table with fixed size and values

Tags: hashtable, glib

I need to create a g_hash_table of a known size (i know the exact number of key) and, at the beginning, I want every value to be the same (let's say 255). Is there a more efficient way than doing:

```
for(int temp=0;temp<NUMBER_OF_KEYS;temp++)
{
    g_hash_table_insert(hashtable, key, 255);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not. `GHashTable` has no support for static instantiation (either empty or from pre-hashed data). There has been [a bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=118210) open about this for 14 years, but it’s unlikely to get fixed unless someone puts forward a concrete use case (and a new patch).

If you are looking to build a constant hash table, you might want to look at using [GNU gperf](https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/) instead of `GHashTable`. (Note that, despite the name, `gperf` is completely unrelated to GLib.)

If you are concerned about the cost of building the entire hash table at once, you could amortise the cost by only inserting each entry when you actually come to read it for the first time — at that point you know the default value for the entry will be 255.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will look int gperf